# MVC View if statment inside foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to put an if statement inside a foreach loop in a Razor view but I get an error `Error   } expected` and if I remove the if statement there are no errors.

I've tried a few different optioned mentioned in other similar questions like wrapping in `<text></text>`, using `@Html.Raw`but all i'm tring to do is set a value for a string variable.

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            string RowColor = "Standard";
            string RowClassName = "row-" + @item.CaseID;
            int StatusDays = int.Parse(@item.StatusDays);

            if (@item.Viewings == 0 && StatusDays >= 14)
            {
                RowColor = "Red";
            }


        <tr class="row-click @RowClassName @RowColor" data-url="/Case/Details/@item.CaseID/">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.RegistrationDate.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
            </td>
        </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your problem is here

```
if (@item.Viewings == 0 && StatusDays >= 14)
```

remove the @ symbol.

```
if (item.Viewings == 0 && StatusDays >= 14)
```

Comment: Had another @ symbol to remove as well then worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this modified code

```
@{
   foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            string RowColor = "Standard";
            string RowClassName = "row-" + item.CaseID;
            int StatusDays = int.Parse(item.StatusDays);

            if (item.Viewings == 0 && StatusDays >= 14)
            {
                RowColor = "Red";
            }


        <tr class="row-click @RowClassName @RowColor" data-url="/Case/Details/@item.CaseID/">
            <td>
                Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CaseID)
            </td>
            <td>
                item.RegistrationDate.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
            </td>
        </tr>
       }
}
```

Comment: Why add the same answer?

Comment: @GlennPacker - Answer is not the same as yours.

Comment: @JBoom - since you have already created a code block using @ { } make sure you are not using any @ symbols withing the code block. See the corrected code

Answer (score 0):

Long time without using razor, but I think the problem is you are using more @ inside your code, for example in

```
 string RowClassName = "row-" + @item.CaseID;
 int StatusDays = int.Parse(@item.StatusDays);
```

Should be

```
 string RowClassName = "row-" + item.CaseID;
 int StatusDays = int.Parse(item.StatusDays);
```